# How to remove double cell borders in HTML tables

Tags: html, html-table, duplicates, width, border

I want a simple 17x2 HTML table with single lines as borders, no spaces between cells etc. [This](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables) online editor returns the following code:

[image: HTML Code]

The output looks like this:[image: Output]

I added `cellspacing="0"` in order to get rid of the white spaces between cells. How do I get rid of the duplicate border between neighbouring cells?

PS.: The Stackoverflow input editor returns an code indentation error, although all indents are in place.

Comment: Paste your code here instead of using an image.

Comment: Sorry, I pasted above code using `` first, but the input editor indicates an indentation error and does not accept the entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `border-collapse: collapse` Property on the table tag.

for example:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

more info
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp